# SQL on multiple lists multiple colums

Tags: sql

I'm looking for some SQL without using a stored procedure for using 3 lists on 3 different columns... something similar to the following.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE
STORES IN(1,2,3,4,5)
AND ITEM IN (11,22,33,44,55)
AND DATE IN (2016, 2017, 2018)
```

Is this possible? subquery's?

Comment: As long as table1 has int fields stores, Item and Date the above query is valid

Comment: Your query should already work.  And your question is...?

Comment: we dont know your table structure, but this works.

Comment: Yes, it's valid, but I can't quite understand what the OP wants.

Comment: Please add more information about your question, because is unclear

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

The query is infact correct if its obvious by schema/table structure meaning data types

```
   .....STORES IN(1,2,3,4,5) --Integer/Number
     AND ITEM IN (11,22,33,44,55)  --Integer/Number
      AND DATE IN (2016, 2017, 2018)  
       -- Integer/Number/Date
```

matching the values put in the filters. Perhaps I think the question needs to be modified.

Comment: I was unaware that I could run a query similar to how I posted. Will the resultset be unique items to all 3 clauses? I'm not sure how to word the question I want to ask... would it be similar to running a join on 3 separate tables?

This data all lives in a single table so I'm trying to get a resultset given 3 different criteria which should result in a single record.

Comment: A JOIN is needed specially when you have to refer other columns in the joined tables plus in case you require more no of columns then rather making your subquery long and complex preferrable is a JOIN. Here, in this case you might not require a join as you dont want a huge no of columns to refer and even you dont require extra other columns

Comment: I was able to resolve my issue by using a subquery and multiple IN clauses.. thank you for the assistance in clarifying its usage. I'm not sure how to close/award this question?